# React Hooks - useState for global state management

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, global-state

I know there is now the Context API which should be used for global app state management.

But I am wondering, is there anything wrong (or not optimal) with managing the global state of the app using useState and passing into props like this?

```
//App.js

function App() {

  const [counterA, setCounterA] =  useState(0);
  const [counterB, setCounterB] =  useState(0);

  let masterStates = {
    counterA: counterA,
    counterB: counterB,
  }

  let masterFunctions = {
    setCounterA: setCounterA,
    setCounterB: setCounterB,
  }


  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <ChildComponent masterStates={masterStates} masterFunctions={masterFunctions} />
      ...
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

Then in my ChildComponent, I can easily access the state and update it like this:

```
//ChildComponent.js

function ChildComponent(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This will successfully log when counterA changes: ", props.masterStates.counterA);
  }, [props.masterStates.counterA]);

  return(
    <button onClick={() => props.masterFunctions.setCounterA(a => a + 1)}>
      {props.masterStates.counterA}
    </button>
  )

}
```

Comment: The only thing "wrong" with prop-drilling is that it can get complex and quickly out of hand. I think this question is asking too much opinion based.

Comment: The context API would be used to propagate the same `useState` data and setter function, so there's really nothing wrong with your approach, it just becomes limited as soon as you have deeply nested components (caveat known as prop drilling).

Comment: there's also the problem that some renders might affect unexpectedly either the data or at least performance... but, at the end of the day... if it is just the two components (parent/child(s))... sure... go ahead and use just the `useState`. add another one and that would be pushing but doable... more than that just use `context API`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the insightful comments! That really helped clear things up for me.

I was not familiar with this term "prop drilling" but now it makes a lot of sense.

I'm leaving here some useful links for anyone who would like to learn a little more about this:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-prop-drilling-and-how-to-avoid-it/

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/props-drilling-in-react-js-934120a4906b

---

**Edit:** I just found this article here where he describes an approach like mine and lays out some of its benefits.

https://dev.to/bytebodger/rethinking-prop-drilling-state-management-in-react-1h61